# Handling exception with list out of range

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract all WC 2019 players batting stats, query got stuck with an error "list index out of range" at the player: http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/player/398438.html

How can I handle exception or PASS to get complete team player stats?

```
url2 = 'http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/player/' + \
       str(player_id) + \
       '.htmlclass=2;template=results;type=batting;view=innings'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url2, context=ctx).read()

temp_data = OrderedDict()
list_of_dict = []

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table_body = bs.find_all('tbody')
rows = table_body[1].find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    temp_data = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(len(cols)):
        temp_data["Runs"] = cols[0]
        temp_data["Mins"] = cols[1]
        temp_data["BF"] = cols[2]
        temp_data["fours"] = cols[3]
        temp_data["sixs"] = cols[4]
        temp_data["SR"] = cols[5]
        temp_data["POS"] = cols[6]
        temp_data["Dismissal"] = cols[7]
        temp_data["Inns"] = cols[8]
        temp_data["Opposition"] = cols[10]
        temp_data["Ground"] = cols[11]
        temp_data["Date"] = cols[12]
        temp_data["player"] = player
        temp_data["playerid"] = player_id
    list_of_dict.append(temp_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
    df
df.to_sql("dummy", con, if_exists="append")
```

I'd like to extract all WC squad wise player stats.

Comment: Please format your code correctly, as it stands it is not a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Also please add the full error traceback to your question

Comment: `try/except`, some cols doesn't have enough fields. Also, your `for i in range(len(cols))` makes no sense, you're iterating 12 times over the same data (cols doesn't change).

Comment: thank h4ze, yeah you are right, can you elaborate on exception handling here

Comment: FlyingTeller: Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 189, in <module>
    rows = table_body[1].find_all('tr')
IndexError: list index out of range